# Battleheart 2: How do you beat Lady of the Deep?

Tags: battleheart

My party is level 29 already, but she just shreds them.

I play Mint, Cedric, November, Kaimani. Tried to weaken her with Rynn, but didn't succeed (is she immune to his effects?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used cleric, rynn, witch and fire mage. I was level 30. Had legendary weapon for dps. Dps had 4 passive talents each. Cleric and tank each had 3 passive talents. Dps has to focus fire adds fast. Keep her out of the big blue pool it heals her. Stay spread and drop adds fast

Comment: Thanks! Looks like I'm not sufficiently prepared yet.